# if run same stored procedure with same name on two different database with same logic but it returns different result for out parameter of procedure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have below test procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(
   IN  DBname VARCHAR(20),
  OUT flag INT   
)
BEGIN
    SET flag=0;   
    IF(DBname='testing')            
     THEN
           SET flag=1;   
     END IF;   
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If I call above procedure using php code using one database db1
it returns out parameter flag as 1 if I pass 1 for calling stored procedure
But If I call same procedure with different database db2 then it returns null value of out parameter.

where is the problem, not getting.

above procedure works fine if I run through Mysqlyog on different database also.

Comment: The procedure will return the same result no matter where you run it which means the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I want to know that if two different database have different variables settings. Is that affect to on stored procedure

Comment: I guess you double checked both databases have the same content...

Comment: but above procedure doesn't required any data to select from database

Comment: How do you "call the above procedure using php" ?

Comment: its a simple procedure

Comment: \DB::statement('CALL test("'.$DBname.'",@flag)');
                         $results = \DB::select('select @flag as flag');  
print_r($results );

Comment: I suggest you run the query directly in mysql using mysql command line then if you get the same result backtrack through all your layers until you find a difference, Also in your previous post on this topic you mentioned that 1 db is on windows and the other on linux is that still the case or are both dbs on the same box?

Comment: its working fine